# What is good practice for building relationships between components in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I trying to think over game architecture in Unity, I face the following problem: there are several ways to build relations between components, and I cannot understand which of them is the most optimal.

For example we have GameplayObject component with following parametres

```
public class GameplayObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    // every gameplay object has chanse of appear on board
    [SerializeField, Min(0)] int m_ChanseOfAppear = 0;

    public int ChanseOfAppear => m_ChanseOfAppear;

    //every gameplay object may be destroyed
    public virtual void Destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

Destroy method can be executed after user input(click or drag is just a few types of input) or another gameplay object can execute destory method. 
For example we have following TapBehaviour component

```
public class CustomDestroyer: MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{    
    public event System.Action OnTap = delegate { };

    IPointerClickHandler.OnPointerClick()
    {
         OnTap();
    }
}
```

We have concrete GameplayObject (for exapmle CustomDestroyer) who should destroy objects in a concrete way. And now it need a dependency for our input component

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(TapBehaviour), typeof(BoxColiider2D))]
public class CustomDestroyer: GameplayObject 
{
    TapBehaviour m_TapBehaviour;
    TapBehaviour TapBehaviour
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_TapBehaviour == null)
                m_TapBehaviour = GetComponent<TapBehaviour>();
            return m_TapBehaviour;
        }
    }


    public override void Destroy()
    {

    }
}
```

But we may do it just in an opposite way: inherit CustomDestroyer from TapBehaviour and use GameplayObject like component.

So the main question is how you build architecture of your projects? When you use component's inheritance, when use just components? May be I'm losing some more preferable ways?

The more you explain to me, the more I will be grateful to you!

And sorry for bad english, just learning it.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Unity, you should exactly know what do you want to do and possible future implementations, then find a way to do it and that doesn't limit your future implementations.

There's not ONE way to relate things in Unity, that's part of its ease of use. Everyone ends up doing things their way.

Try to find a solution that balances readability and efficiency, and stick to the newest components which are usually better overall.

Edit: Forgot to say that if you're a code guy try not to abuse the power of scripts since unity was designed for avoiding code. The UI has a lot of options that, in comparison with writing code, seem like magic.

Answer (score 0):

Unity offers a great degree of freedom regarding architecture, its sometimes overwhelming when you can successfully do stuff in so many different ways that will all work. Regarding your question - in terms of future proofing I would lean towards using seperate components (aka single responsibility), loosely tied together using interfaces (like IDestroy instead of concrete types), the idea is to, whenever possible, avoid interdependency of components.

But for a great deal of cases inheritance with overrides will be fine, and refactoring is often painless (and there's many ways to automate editor tasks if you go too far down one of the alleys) so my advice would be: do not overcomplicate things, do it as simple as possible, but not simpler